# Watch rails views and reload page on changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I'm currently using webpacker with page reloading on css/js changes and it all works just great. I was wondering - is that possible to do the same for rails views? It would be great if updating erb or slim view could trigger a webpack page refresh (ideally without rebuilding entire js/css bundle).

I know there are solutions like guard and browsersync for that but i would love to avoid using yet another deamon running in the background.

Comment: I would consider using Guard as it can both run guard-webpack and guard-livereload from a single daemon (although it might use different threads). You can also simply adapt it to do whatever you want through the guardfile and its Ruby DSL. It can also run Minitest or RSpec on file changes for continuous testing which is much more valuable IMHO.

Comment: You can just hit refresh in your browser when you change Views right? Or do you really want to trigger page refresh automatically?

Answer (score 2):

I would use guard-livereload (https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload) and exclude js and css files since are already watched by webpacker-dev-server.

```
guard 'livereload' do
  watch(%r{app/views/.+\.(erb|haml|slim)})
  watch(%r{app/helpers/.+\.rb})      
  watch(%r{config/locales/.+\.yml})      
end
```